# installing VHDL on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I want to learn VHDL for noc simulation (specifically noc router and buffer micro-architecture). I just know that VHDL is a programming language but I have no idea how can I use it and which simulators use VHDL. now these are my questions:
 does ubuntu suit for installing VHDL? and if the answer is yes, which simulator is good for noc architecture? and how can I install VHDL and that simulator on ubuntu step by step? and from where I can download a free version of that?

Comment: you can use "ghdl".More info  [here](http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_make_a_VHDL_design_in_Ubuntu/Debian).

Answer (score 0):

GHDL is available for many platforms. It supports VHDL 87, 93, 2002 and 2008. The user documentation is hosted on [RTFD](http://ghdl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

You can download [*.deb packages](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/tag/v0.33) for GHDL from GHDLs GitHub repository.

Or you compile it yourself from source. It's quite easy when you use the LLVM back-end. [Build instructions](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/blob/master/BUILD.txt).